# How to execute different partsof the JS code in one scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I have several script blocks depend on each other. I need to perform them in one scope.

My attempt:

```
var scopeWrapper = {}; 

with(scopeWrapper) {
    (function() {
        this.run = function(code) {
            eval(code);
        };
    }).call(scopeWrapper);
}

scopeWrapper.run('function test() { alert("passed"); }');
scopeWrapper.run('test();');
```

I get 'test is not defined' error. It seems that the code is executed in different scopes.
Why is this happening?

Comment: And why would you be doing this in the first place?

Comment: @epascarello Read the code, he's making a script runner...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I know that, I am wondering *why*, not what it does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:** [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409639/how-to-execute-different-partsof-the-js-code-in-one-scope/15409716#comment21790093_15409716) pointed out my original answer was wrong, he is correct. Since `eval` runs in its own scope and the function constructor still runs in function scope according to the [spec](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.2) this is not possible with either.

While I have done this sort of thing myself several times with node.js using the `vm` module where you get much finer grain of control over where your code executes, it seems browsers require a different approach.

The only way you can share variables in such a way is to do so in the global scope of JavaScript execution (possibly, in an iframe). One way you could do this is script tag injection.

```
function run(code){
    var sc = document.createElement("script");
    sc.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    sc.innerHTML = code;
    document.body.appendChild(sc);
}

run("var x = 5");
run("document.write(x)");
```

([here is this code in action](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/exynf))

As for the scope wrapper, instead of injecting them in the same frame inject them in another `iframe`. That will scope their window object to that iframe and will allow you to share context.

I humbly apologize for my previous answer, I misread the spec. I hope this answer helps you.

I'm leaving my previous answer here because I still believe it provides some insight into how `eval` and the `Function` constructor work.

---

When running code in non-strict mode `eval` runs in the current context of your page
After your function declaration is done, the scope it was declared in dies, and with it the function.

Consider using the [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Example.3A_Specifying_arguments_with_the_Function_constructor) and then `.call`ing it

In your case that would be something like:

```
var scopeWrapper = {}; 
scopeWrapper.run = function(code){
    var functionToRun = new Function(code);
    functionToRun.call(scopeWrapper);
}
scopeWrapper.run('this.test = function() { alert("passed"); }');
scopeWrapper.run("this.test()")
```

Here is a reference directly [from the spec:](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.2)

> If there is no calling context or if the eval code is not being evaluated by a direct call (15.1.2.1.1) to the eval function then,
>   Initialize the execution context as if it was a global execution context using the eval code as C as described in 10.4.1.1.

If this code is run in the node.js consider using the [vm](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module. Also note that this approach is still not secure in the way it'll allow code you run to change your code.

Comment: I like this idea (+1), but it think it's worth noting that really "scopeWrapper" is executing everything in a shared *context*, not a shared *scope*.  Note that if you replace `this.test = func...` with `var test = func...` it wouldn't work (unlike if it were really the same scope).

Comment: I don't think the `Function` constructor helps anything, the function's scope dies as well - it would not work with `run('function test() { alert("passed"); }')`. Your assignment code would work with `eval` as well

Comment: @Bergi See edit. I would like to hear your opinion if you have time.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. The idea of using an iframe's global scope is nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

`test` only exists in the scope of `this.run` and only at call time :

```
// global scope
(function(){
  // local scope (equivalent of your "run" function scope)
  eval('function f(){};');
  console.log(f); // prints "function f(){}"
})();
console.log(f); // prints "ReferenceError: f is not defined"
```

Each call of `run` creates a new scope in which each `code` is evaluated separately.

Comment: He is setting this.run . Also, the problem was with the way _eval_ context is decided (see my answer) and not with the scope where _run_ is defined...

Comment: I meant "inside `this.run`".