# How to execute JavaScript and get the browser's console output with JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I execute JavaScript I get from the user via a text field, inside the console and get the browser's console's output directly with JavaScript and/or jQuery?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist What's the risk here ?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: It all depends on what that code is doing. I wouldn't say jsFiddle or JSBin are a "pretty big security risk"

Comment: jsFiddle does exactly this.

Comment: @dystroy Actually, having thought about it some more, if they're not saving it then it's not going to be an issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you programmatically access the Firebug console output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375522/can-you-programmatically-access-the-firebug-console-output) and similar ones

Comment: @Bergi Nope, I'm not going to use Firebug Console

Comment: @Sazid: What else do you mean by "browser's console" then? They are debugging tools, and not accessible from the javascript environment. What do you need this for?

Comment: @Bergi Well, I am actually trying to create something like Jsfiddle which will run on the client side/end user's PC.

Comment: @Sazid: But that doesn't need the browser's console, does it?

Comment: @Bergi Please, will you tell me, how can I achieve that then?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) for that :

```
 console.log(eval('('+$('#yourInput').val()+')'))
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/auzQa/)

Comment: You shouldn't use `eval` anywhere! It is considered as evil! Here, look at this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: Ok, but what does the eval() function is doing here?
I also heard its evil-ness.

Comment: eval evaluates/performs the JavaScript expressions/statements passed as argument to it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: @akash4eva Stop propagating irrational fears. `eval` is perfectly suited to this situation.

Comment: `eval` is fine. It becomes evil when you take user input data into your application with `eval`. But evaluating user code with `eval` is totally fine.

Comment: Solid answer +1 op might also find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409639/how-to-execute-different-partsof-the-js-code-in-one-scope/15409716#15409716

Comment: But, what about getting the output from the console? Please someone tell me!

Comment: You mean you want to eval what the user types in the console ? [There's no function for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console).